# Json Data into UITableView in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have to store the json data to UITableView with different section header. Please let me know what will be the JSON format and objective-c code to display them in UITableView using xib file? The UITableView will contain name of different person under different category(Section) like family, friends, workplace etc.

eg-

```
Friends
  Sam
  Max
Family
 Taylor
 Nick
Workplace
 maxwel
 sarah
```

Comment: I am getting the data from webservice and display it normally in UITable View without Section.

Comment: what is your requirement and for that what have u done???

Comment: I want To display a list of friends of mine under various section just like google plus circle.

Comment: so whats the problem and what have u done???

Comment: i already mentioned it in my question.

Comment: What question?  You haven't asked a legitimate question yet.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide us with the JSON structure. However below it will give you an idea how to request the JSON data and it'll put the JSON inside an NSArray which you can then pass the data into the UITableView.

Make sure you set the URL to the URL of where you wanting to get the JSON data from.

**Viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *UItableView;

    NSArray *arrayName;
    NSMutableData *dataName;
}

@end
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Title";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL HERE"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    dataName = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)Data
{
    [dataName appendData:Data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSArray *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];

    if ([responseDict isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        arrayName = responseDict;
        [UItableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error from JSON");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayName count];
}

NSString *getStringID(id obj)
{
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? obj : nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = getStringID([[arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Label1"]);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = getStringID([[arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Label2"]);

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Since Opie has chosen to not reveal the structure of his JSON, there's no way to know how to display it.

Comment: @HotLicks I know and i've given him an idea of how JSON would work with UITableView. It would be better if he did give us an idea about how his JSON was structured